# Swift & Firebase | using a textField to get a piece of data and query firebase with the data

Tags: string, swift, firebase, textfield

I have a very strange problem, I have a text field where the user can enter a username and then search for it using firebase... but in my firebase query I get the error `Static member 'init(stringInterpolationSegment:)' cannot be used on instance of type 'String'` and what really does not make sense is that I have the same exact code (i think?!?!) else where in my app and it is working perfectly. The code is all below...

**View controller code**

```
import UIKit
import Spring
import Firebase

class searchUsernameViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var usernameField: DesignableTextField!
@IBOutlet var resultFoundText: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var usernameText: UILabel!

@IBAction func searchPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let username = usernameField.text

    if usernameField.text == "" {
        print("oh no")
    } else {
        let checkWaitingRef = Firebase(url:"https://test.firebaseio.com/users")
        checkWaitingRef.queryOrderedByChild("username").queryEqualToValue("\(username!)")
            .observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in


                usernameText.text = snapshot.value.valueForKey("username")
        })
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your code worked fine in my project.

Comment: @Abhishek729 it worked fine in mine as well :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is still confusing me a lot... but It's fixed now. What I did to fix it was copy all the code from the view controller that had the bit of code I needed and then just take away what ever wasn't needed. It worked?!?! I don't know why but it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Always trim the fat :)